# How can I generate an alphanumeric string using only POSIX-compliant shell tools?

Tags: string, shell, posix

I'm trying to generate an eight character alphanumeric string using POSIX compliant shell tools. I'm trying to use /dev/urandom to produce this string (incidentally I did not know that /dev/random and /dev/urandom are not specified by POSIX, but I'm going with it because they are present on Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS, AIX etc.)

There are a plethora of guides that show how this can be done, but none that I've found are close to being posixly correct. In particular I keep seeing the use of head -c (the -c argument is not defined in POSIX) like below:

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo ''
```

Another concern I have is that almost none of the solutions I have seen respect the difference between a byte stream and a  character stream, which makes me worried that I'm producing strings that are unsafe.

This is the best I can seem to come up with, but I don't fully understand it:

```
strings -n 1 < /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

It's POSIX compliant (minus the /dev/urandom) but have I achieved my end correctly? If so, is there a better way to achive this end? It would also be cool if there was a way to produce a random string without /dev/urandom, but I think I'm dreaming on that one.

Comment: Must all alphanumeric characters be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `awk`, which POSIX mandates provide a `rand` function.

```
$ cat password.awk
BEGIN {
    srand();
    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    s = "";
    for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
        s = s "" substr(chars, int(rand()*62), 1);
    }
    print s
}
$ awk -f password.awk
Cl7A4KVx
```

(This can almost certainly be code-golfed into something shorter; my `awk` skills are somewhat limited.)

If you need multiple passwords, pass the number needed as an argument so that you don't need to run `awk` more than once per second:

```
BEGIN {
  srand();
  chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    s = "";
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
      s = s "" substr(chars, int(rand()*62), 1);
    }
    print s
  }
}
```

To pass a value of `n`, run as `awk -v n=5 -f password.awk` to generate 5 passwords.

Alternatively, you can pass a different seed directly to `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  srand(seed);
  chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
  s = "";
  for(i=0;i<8;i++) {
      s = s "" substr(chars, int(rand()*62), 1);
  }
  print s
}
```

with `awk -v seed=$newseed -f password.akw`. Note that `newseed` itself needs to have a different value each time, but using a simple sequential sequence of seeds should be sufficient.

```
seed=$(date +%s)
awk -v seed=$seed -f password.awk; seed=$((seed + 1))
awk -v seed=$seed -f password.awk; seed=$((seed + 1))
awk -v seed=$seed -f password.awk; seed=$((seed + 1))
# etc
```

Comment: I really like this answer. But why are you piping /dev/null into the awk -f command? It seems to work with or without the ' < /dev/null' appended to the command.

Comment: Hm, I never noticed that. I'm not sure if that's standard behavior, to ignore standard input if the only pattern are `BEGIN` and/or `END`, or if that's an extension. I'll do a little research and comment on the need for it.

Comment: OK, POSIX does specify that standard input is not read if there are no patterns or actions (where apparently the pseudo-patterns `BEGIN` and `END` do not count), so the redirection is not necessary here.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like awk is generating these random strings using the time. If you run the script multiple times in quick succession, you can see that awk can only generate one random string per second.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to use some combination of the current time and the current process ID as the seed, although it's not clear if there is a POSIX-compliant way to get either from inside `awk`. Instead, I'll add a solution that can return multiple passwords in one run, which should eliminate the need to run more than once per second.

Comment: Cool. I don't see it as a problem that it uses the time as a seed, it just kind of defeats my use case because in real life that would mean my scripts would need to sleep for one second every time it needs a new random string.

Comment: Note the second suggestion, which passes an explicit seed to each call of `awk`, rather than relying on the default seed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
head -n 1 /dev/urandom | hexdump | head -n 1 | sed ‘s/0+| //g’ | sed ‘s/\(......\).*/\1/g’
```

Comment: Did you mean `head /dev/urandom` ?

Comment: @cdarke I sure did!

Answer (score 0):

Eight "random" alphanumeric characters with only the POSIX toolbox? Very well, a challenge!

Let's begin by observing that [Base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding uses almost only alphanumerics (and `+` and `/`) and the wonderful POSIX people have added Base-64 support with `-m` to the [uuencode](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uuencode.html) utility.

Next, where do we get some (pseudo? almost?) randomness from? Observe again that the current list of processes is pretty arbitrary, especially if it contains all processes in long format, with CPU time and whatnot.

We condense the ps entropy further with the POSIXly [cksum](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cksum.html) utility because the first line of ps output is pretty constant and we would have to look for a suitable line in the uuencoded output (which is messy).

So far we have

```
$ ps|cksum|uuencode -m -
begin-base64 644 -
MjUwMDcyMjY3NSAxOTExCg==
====
```

Running this a few times we notice (or know) that the first two characters in the second line are not quite random, since they contain the length of the line. So we extract the 8 characters from position 3 in line 2 with

```
$ ps|cksum|uuencode -m -|sed -n 's,[+/],0,g; 2s/^..\(........\).*/\1/p'
kzNDkzMj
$ ps|cksum|uuencode -m -|sed -n 's,[+/],0,g; 2s/^..\(........\).*/\1/p'
I0NTcxND
```

and transpose the unwanted `+` and `/` to `0`. You are almost guaranteed a different result with each invocation since the process IDs of the commands in the triple pipe are different with each run.

Voila! No `/dev/urandom` needed :-)